# Which libraries are included in g++?

Tags: c++, g++

I've so far been unable to find documentation on which libraries are included in g++ by default. My assumption is that it includes only the standard C++ libraries; is this correct?

If not, what else is included extra or missing, and where can I find this documented?

Thank You!

Comment: Standard library. That's it.

Comment: Depends on the implementation/distribution. For example, with https://nuwen.net/mingw.html you get lots of goodies.

Comment: It also comes with various extensions and utilities. The place to look is the `GCC` Documentation.

Comment: I'm more interested in *why* you ask this question. What is the problem you have that lead to this question? Or is it just plain curiosity?

Comment: It's mostly curiosity. I don't have any particular problem right now, but it's good to know what tools are available

Comment: I think we're all assuming slightly different things by your question. Are you asking what headers are available, what libraries do you get when you download gcc, or what libraries are automatically linked? What's your platform?

Comment: Libraries that are installed when you download G++, per the question topic

Comment: Assuming you have many `.pc` in the `PKG_CONFIG_PATH`, refer to [this](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/pkg-config-exists-fails-but-list-all-lists-the-package-4175563319/) discussion.

Comment: @JesperJuhl: Are you saying that [`libquadmath`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libquadmath/) is part of the Standard Library? It's definitely included with g++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The library that comes with g++ by default is libstdc++. That is basically the GNU implementation of the C++ standard library. You can find the documentation of libstdc++ on the gcc website under [The GNU C++ Library](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/).